# How can I extract a selected rectangle from a screen as a top-view image?

Tags: python, computer-vision, opencv

I've written some code to detect the computer screen in an image. I need to do some work on pixels that are in the center of that selected rectangle. How can I extract the selected rectangle as a rectangular image?

```
import imutils
import cv2
image = cv2.imread('test-img/imgRec3.jpg')
ratio = image.shape[0] / 300.0
image = imutils.resize(image, height=300)
realImage = image.copy()

# convert the image to grayscale, blur it, and find edges in the image
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 11, 17, 17)
edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 30, 200)

cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, 
cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:10]
screenCnt = None

# loop over our contours
for c in cnts:
   # approximate the contour
   peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
   approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.015 * peri, True)

   if len(approx) == 4:
        screenCnt = approx
        break

cv2.drawContours(image, [screenCnt], -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
cv2.imshow("image", realImage)
cv2.imshow("Screen Rec", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Use Perspective Transformation: https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_geometric_transformations/py_geometric_transformations.html#perspective-transformation

Comment: check this post , it might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55881270/how-to-delete-a-certain-part-of-an-image/55883321#55883321

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55714213/10699171) deals with a similar question

Comment: Could you post the original image?

Comment: @nathancy  I added it

Answer (score 1):

Using skimage you could do it like that:

```
def transform(intersections, image):
    w,h = get_orientation()
    a = np.array([0,h])
    b = np.array([w,h])
    c = np.array([w,0])
    d = np.array([0,0])
    tf = skimage.transform.estimate_transform("projective",
        dst=np.vstack((a,b,c,d)),
        src=intersections)
    invtf = tf.inverse
    transformedImage = skimage.transform.warp(image=image,inverse_map=invtf, output_shape=(h,w))
    return transformedImage

fig,(ax0,ax1) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(15,8))

transformed_image = transform(sorted_intersec, img[index] )
ax0.imshow(transformed_image,cmap="gray")

ax1.imshow(img[index])
```

intersections are your 4 edges. Keep in mind you have to put them in in the correct order.

Comment: thanks but what is get_orientation()? It is defined function in cv or somewhere?

Comment: Sorry went to bed. Forgot to add this function. It's quite similar to what @nathancy does. Since his answer works well I'll leave it like that.

Answer (score 1):

To extract the selected rectangle as a rectangular image, we can use a [perspective transformation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/da/d6e/tutorial_py_geometric_transformations.html) to obtain a top-down view of the image. Since you were able to find the bounding box of the rectangle, we can use those coordinates as the corners of the new image. To begin, we separate the four corners into individual points given to us by `cv2.approxPolyDP()`. We reorder the points into a clockwise orientation (top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left) using this function:

```
def order_corner_points(corners):
    # Separate corners into individual points
    # Index 0 - top-right
    #       1 - top-left
    #       2 - bottom-left
    #       3 - bottom-right
    corners = [(corner[0][0], corner[0][1]) for corner in corners]
    top_r, top_l, bottom_l, bottom_r = corners[0], corners[1], corners[2], corners[3]
    return (top_l, top_r, bottom_r, bottom_l)
```

Now with the isolated corner points, we find the new width and length dimensions for the top-down image. We can obtain the transformation matrix using `cv2.getPerspectiveTransform()` and actually obtain the transformed image using `cv2.warpPerspective()`.

```
def perspective_transform(image, corners):

    # Order points in clockwise order
    ordered_corners = order_corner_points(corners)
    top_l, top_r, bottom_r, bottom_l = ordered_corners

    # Determine width of new image which is the max distance between 
    # (bottom right and bottom left) or (top right and top left) x-coordinates
    width_A = np.sqrt(((bottom_r[0] - bottom_l[0]) ** 2) + ((bottom_r[1] - bottom_l[1]) ** 2))
    width_B = np.sqrt(((top_r[0] - top_l[0]) ** 2) + ((top_r[1] - top_l[1]) ** 2))
    width = max(int(width_A), int(width_B))

    # Determine height of new image which is the max distance between 
    # (top right and bottom right) or (top left and bottom left) y-coordinates
    height_A = np.sqrt(((top_r[0] - bottom_r[0]) ** 2) + ((top_r[1] - bottom_r[1]) ** 2))
    height_B = np.sqrt(((top_l[0] - bottom_l[0]) ** 2) + ((top_l[1] - bottom_l[1]) ** 2))
    height = max(int(height_A), int(height_B))

    # Construct new points to obtain top-down view of image in 
    # top_r, top_l, bottom_l, bottom_r order
    dimensions = np.array([[0, 0], [width - 1, 0], [width - 1, height - 1], 
                    [0, height - 1]], dtype = "float32")

    # Convert to Numpy format
    ordered_corners = np.array(ordered_corners, dtype="float32")

    # Find perspective transform matrix
    matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(ordered_corners, dimensions)

    # Return the transformed image
    return cv2.warpPerspective(image, matrix, (width, height))
```

**Obtained bounding box coordinates**

[image: Obtained bounding box coordinates]

**Extracted rectangle**

[image: Extracted rectangle]

Full code

```
import imutils
import cv2
import numpy as np

def order_corner_points(corners):
    # Separate corners into individual points
    # Index 0 - top-right
    #       1 - top-left
    #       2 - bottom-left
    #       3 - bottom-right
    corners = [(corner[0][0], corner[0][1]) for corner in corners]
    top_r, top_l, bottom_l, bottom_r = corners[0], corners[1], corners[2], corners[3]
    return (top_l, top_r, bottom_r, bottom_l)

def perspective_transform(image, corners):

    # Order points in clockwise order
    ordered_corners = order_corner_points(corners)
    top_l, top_r, bottom_r, bottom_l = ordered_corners

    # Determine width of new image which is the max distance between 
    # (bottom right and bottom left) or (top right and top left) x-coordinates
    width_A = np.sqrt(((bottom_r[0] - bottom_l[0]) ** 2) + ((bottom_r[1] - bottom_l[1]) ** 2))
    width_B = np.sqrt(((top_r[0] - top_l[0]) ** 2) + ((top_r[1] - top_l[1]) ** 2))
    width = max(int(width_A), int(width_B))

    # Determine height of new image which is the max distance between 
    # (top right and bottom right) or (top left and bottom left) y-coordinates
    height_A = np.sqrt(((top_r[0] - bottom_r[0]) ** 2) + ((top_r[1] - bottom_r[1]) ** 2))
    height_B = np.sqrt(((top_l[0] - bottom_l[0]) ** 2) + ((top_l[1] - bottom_l[1]) ** 2))
    height = max(int(height_A), int(height_B))

    # Construct new points to obtain top-down view of image in 
    # top_r, top_l, bottom_l, bottom_r order
    dimensions = np.array([[0, 0], [width - 1, 0], [width - 1, height - 1], 
                    [0, height - 1]], dtype = "float32")

    # Convert to Numpy format
    ordered_corners = np.array(ordered_corners, dtype="float32")

    # Find perspective transform matrix
    matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(ordered_corners, dimensions)

    # Return the transformed image
    return cv2.warpPerspective(image, matrix, (width, height))

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
ratio = image.shape[0] / 300.0
image = imutils.resize(image, height=300)
realImage = image.copy()

# convert the image to grayscale, blur it, and find edges in the image
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 11, 17, 17)
edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 30, 200)

cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, 
cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:10]
screenCnt = None

# loop over our contours
for c in cnts:
    # approximate the contour
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.015 * peri, True)

    if len(approx) == 4:
        screenCnt = approx
        transformed = perspective_transform(realImage, screenCnt)
        break

cv2.drawContours(image, [screenCnt], -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
cv2.imshow("image", realImage)
cv2.imshow("Screen Rec", image)
cv2.imshow("transformed", transformed)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: No problem :) Consider accepting the answer to let others know your issue is resolved